# THREE JS: Axonometric projection (Isometric view, Dimetric view and Trimetric view) in perspective camera

Tags: three.js

How can I set the camera angle to Axonometric Projections (Isometric View) in Perspective Camera? Can anyone share me some calculations for it?

Comment: Any reason you dont want to use orthoCamera?

Comment: Yes! @manthrax Not any specific reason but the requirement is to use it and I have to use perspective camera only! and Since, I load some big models like buildings and lands which can also be some specific reason!